# Why my Batch is not updating the field

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I am having one batch on Accounts which is not updating.
I want to put the Sum of all the Normalized Accounts from all the invoices related to Accounts if the Status <> "invoice_canceled" and category <> "Monthly". I want to put in the newly created number type field called All_Time_Revenue in the Account object.
Please have a look at my code and tell me where I am wrong.

```
global class BatchAccountRevenue implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Schedulable
{

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        String query = 'Select Id, Name,All_Time_Revenue_c  from Account';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope)
    {
        for(Account a : scope)
        {

       AggregateResult[] agList = [SELECT SUM(Normalized_Amount__c) totalSum FROM Invoice__c where Normalized_Amount__c!= null and Id=:a.id];

       a.All_Time_Revenue_c = (double)agList[0].get('totalSum');
        }
        update scope;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
     global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        BatchAccountRevenue batchable = new BatchAccountRevenue();
        Database.executeBatch(batchable, 300);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your aggregate query returns no results.

```
AggregateResult[] agList = [SELECT SUM(Normalized_Amount__c) totalSum FROM Invoice__c where Normalized_Amount__c!= null and Id=:a.id];
```

The `Id` of an `Invoice__c` will never be equal to that of an `Account`, `a`. You need to be querying on the relationship field from `Invoice__c` to `Account`.

The query should also be outside the loop. That's where you get the value of the aggregate result. Do something like

```
AggregateResult[] agList = [SELECT Account__c, SUM(Normalized_Amount__c) totalSum FROM Invoice__c where Normalized_Amount__c!= null and Account__c IN :scope GROUP BY Account__c];
```

outside your `for` loop.

Then, loop over your aggregate results and build a `Map<Id, Decimal>` from Account Id to total value, and finally loop over `scope` and perform your updates. Bear in mind that not every `Account` in scope may have a corresponding value - if there's no `Invoice__c` associated, you won't get an `AggregateResult` for that `Account`.